# Print the value of a column in a dataframe that is not contained in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'System':['b0001','b0002']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'System':['b0001']})
```

I want to print the value in column System of df1 that is NOT contained in column System of df2. The output should only be:

```
b0002
```

My current code is:

```
for i in df1.index:
    if df1.System[i] not in df2.System:
        print (df1.System[i])
```

But the output is:

```
b0001 
b0002
```

I cant'f figure out why it still prints out `b0001`. I've tried with `isin` and the output is the same.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: df1[~df1.System.isin(df2.System)]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pandas way of doing this is to use `isin` as follows:

```
df1[~df1.System.isin(df2.System)]
```

Output:

```
  System
1  b0002
```

However, to do it the way you are doing you are missing `.values`:

```
for i in df1.index:
    if df1.System[i] not in df2.System.values:
        print (df1.System[i])
```

Output:

```
b0002
```

Answer (score 3):

`numpy`

```
np.setdiff1d(df1.System.values, df2.System.values)

array(['b0002'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# This solution only prints unique elements in df1 which are not in df2

np.setdiff1d(df1,df2)
Out[236]: array(['b0002'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use sets

```
set(df1.system).difference(set(df2.system))
```